# Does canonical commute with canonical?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to learn some algebraic geometry at the moment, and on multiple occasions we need to check some isomorphisms, say of sheaves on a ringed space. This is mostly done by checking isomorphisms on stalks, and most of the time there are canonical isomorphisms of the stalks of the two sheaves. However, I think we would need to check that the isomorphisms on stalks are induced by the map we are working with. Now if this map was also constructed canonically, is this automatic? So, does in some sense canonical commute with canonical?

For example, if we have an affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and a family of $A$-modules $(M_i)_{i\in I}$, then there is an isomorphism $$\widetilde{\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i}\stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}\bigoplus_{i\in I}\widetilde{M_i}.$$ We get a canonical morphism from the left to the right, and the stalks are canonically isomorphic, so does canonical commute with canonical here in the sense that the isomorphism on stalks is induced by our morphism?

As another example, in the answer of this question [$\mathscr{F}\rightarrow i_*(i^*\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism for $i:V(\mathscr{I})\rightarrow X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4147527/mathscrf-rightarrow-i-i-mathscrf-is-an-isomorphism-for-iv-mathscr/4147942#4147942), we have that the morphism $\mathscr{F}\rightarrow i_*(i^*\mathscr{F})$ corresponds affine locally to the canonical morphism $M\rightarrow (A/I\otimes_AM)_A$, which I believe right away, because both are canonical. However, the proof of adjunction for modules in Goertz/Wedhorn is stated as a composition of canonical isomorphisms $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(f^*\mathscr{G},\mathcal{F})\stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}\operatorname{Hom}_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}(f^{-1}\mathscr{G},\mathscr{F})\stackrel{\simeq}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathscr{G},f_*\mathscr{F}),$$ and I think in our example we left out the middle step. Does this give the same because everything is canonical?

Comment: "Because everything is canonical" is not rigorous reasoning, but it does often work.

Comment: *Canonical* is not a rigorously defined word in this context. Usually what's meant is that the object is naturally occurring in some sense (or, if you're a religious person, God-given). But of course there might be two (or more!) naturally-occurring maps from one object to another. Often this occurs in situations in which there is a binary choice available. For instance, there are two completely natural (but different) isomorphisms from the group of unit quaternions  to the group SU$_2(\mathbf{C})$, got by using the action by left multiplication or by right multiplication by the conjugate.

Comment: The upshot is that you cannot simply say that both maps are canonical and therefore equal; you should write down the formula for your maps. If you do that in the situation you are looking at, you will see that they are indeed the same.

Comment: @ZhenLin Would you advice to be satisfied with "because everything is canonical", or is it quite necessarry to go through every single detail in order to learn things properly?

Comment: @Stephen Is there a qualitive difference in the meaning of $\textit{natural}$ and $\textit{canonical}$? Like, is canonical always natural, but natural is not always canonical? Or are these words used interchangeably, and are not really properly defined?

Comment: Unlike *canonical map*, in some contexts *natural map* has a rigorous technical meaning: the term *natural map* is often used interchangeably with *morphism of functors* to describe a homomorphism from one functor to another. (And also in this situation, there are often many morphisms---the endomorphism ring of a functor can be a large and interesting object).